# Angular 2 : Apply styles to child component's child node from parent is not applying

Tags: css, angular, angular2-directives

below is my code.

```
Component({
  selector: 'riceit-my-order',
  templateUrl: './my-order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-order.component.scss']
})
```

in my-order.component.scss file i have

```
.row.orderNow{
    display:none; 
}
host(.in-menu){
    border-right:none;
    .row.orderNow{
        display:block; 
    }
}
```

when I apply `in-menu` class to the child component from the parent, `border-right:none` style is applied to the child component but the child node with the selector `.row.orderNow` is not getting affected with the `display:block` property.

Answer (score 0):

I found two answers for this issue.

1)used traditional css styling in scss file like this

```
:host(.in-menu){
    border-right:none;
}
:host(.in-menu) .row.orderNow{
    display:block; 
}
```

insted of

```
host(.in-menu){
    border-right:none;
    .row.orderNow{
        display:block; 
    }
}
```

it seems there is an issue with the angular 2 selectUrl feature, it is not converting the scss to css properly.

2)Use a npm module like gulp-sass or [scss-2-css](https://github.com/yaswanthsvist/scss-2-css)  to properly convert scss to css file, and use that css in styleUrls if you do not want to compromise on scss full features.